# Confusion about generating intermediate code for control-of-flow statements in the dragon book

Tags: compiler-construction, control-flow, codegen

Section 6.6.3 of the dragon book (Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools 2nd Edition) describes how to translate the flow-of-control statements like `if`/`if-else`/`while` into intermediate code.

For example,

> The translation of `if (B) S1` consists of `B.code` followed by `S1.code`. **Within `B.code` are jumps based on the value of `B`**. If `B` is true, control flows to the first instruction of `S1.code`, and if `B` is false, control flows to the instruction immediately following `S1.code`.

> The labels for the jumps in `B.code` and `S.code` are managed using inherited
> attributes. **With a boolean expression `B`, we associate two labels: `B.true`, the label to which control flows if `B` is true, and `B.false`, the label to which control flows if `B` is false**. With a statement `S`, we associate an inherited attribute `S.next` denoting a label for the instruction immediately after the code for `S`.

I understand the translation. It lets `B` to generate the `goto` jumps based on the value of `B`. Since `B` itself does not know where to jump. Therefore, we associate it with two inherited attributes `B.true` and `B.false`, which are provided by the node `S`.

I am wondering is this translation unnecessarily complicated? Why do not **let `S` generate the `branch` instruction** based on the value of `B`. Similary, is the inherited attribute `S.next` necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer in Section 7.4.1 of the book "Engineering a Compiler (2nd Edition)":

> Traditionally, two representations have been proposed for boolean values: a **numerical encoding** and a **positional encoding**. The former assigns specific values to true and false and manipulates them using the target machine’s arithmetic and logical operations. The latter approach encodes the value of the expression as a position in the executable code. It uses comparisons and conditional branches to evaluate the expression; the different control-flow paths represent the result of evaluation. Each approach works well for some examples, but not for others.

The dragon book uses the **positional encoding**.